# If the coordinates or components $X_i$ are smooth for all chart of manifold $M$ then the vector field $X$ is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

**Question:** Prove that a vector field $X$ is smooth if and only if its coordinates (or components) $X_i$ are smooth for all chart of manifold $M$.

I have the solution of the forward direction, if vector field $X$ is smooth then its coordinates (or components) $X_i$ are smooth for all chart of manifold $M$ by taking the charts $(U,\varphi)$ of $M$ and $(\pi^{-1}(U),\Phi)$ of $TM$, then the corresponding local representation

$$\Phi\circ X\circ \varphi^{-1}: \varphi(U)\rightarrow \Phi(\pi^{-1}(U))=\varphi(U)\times\mathbb R $$
is smooth, where

$$\pi:TM\rightarrow M,\quad \pi(v)=x\quad\text{if }v\in T_xM$$
$$\Phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow \varphi(U)\times\mathbb R^m$$
defined by $\Phi(v):=(\varphi(\pi(v)),\bar\varphi(v))$
where, $$\bar\varphi:T_xM\rightarrow\mathbb R^m,\quad \bar\varphi(v):=(\varphi\circ\alpha)'(0)$$

And looking by $\left(\Phi \circ X \circ \varphi^{-1}\right)(a)$ we have the local representation is smooth.

But I couldn't understand how to solve the reverse direction. Any hint or solution will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of smoothness of a vector-field you are using?

Comment: Definition: A vector field $X$ on a manifold $M$ is a cross-section in $TM$ which assigns to every point $x\in M$ a tangent vector $X(x)$ such that the map $M\rightarrow TM$ so obtained is smooth. @Didier Actually the lecturer didn't go through this topic (definitions, theorems) and mostly skip.

Comment: Ok. Now, what is the definition for a map $f \colon M \to TM$ to be smooth? Translate it for a vector field, and notice that the "for all charts" can be substituted with "there exists a chart" in the definition of smoothness. Use some particular charts of the tangent bundle $TM$ and... notice the tautological aspect of the question!

Comment: $X: M \rightarrow TM$ is smooth at $p \in M$ if there are coordinate charts $(U, \varphi)$ around $p$ and $(V, \psi)$ around $X(p)$ such that $X(U) \subseteq V$ and such that the composition
$$
\psi \circ X \circ \varphi^{-1}: \varphi(U) \rightarrow \psi(V)
$$
is smooth. The function $X$ is called a smooth map from $M$ to $TM$ if it is smooth at all $p \in M$. I was wondering how to choose **some particular chart** as you suggested, Like I guess the above projection map might play that role, $(\pi^{-1}(U),\Phi)$.

Comment: But it seems I am using circular argument, like maybe I not using the component of $X$ rather the vector field in the above. @Didier Can you suggest me the right direction, please

Comment: Nothing circular at all: with this specific choice of charts, $X$ has the nice form $(x^1,\ldots,x^n) \mapsto (x^1,\ldots,x^n, X^1(x^1,\ldots,x^n),\ldots,X^n(x^1,\ldots,x^n))$, and now, the question becomes tautological. You just have to know that a map from an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ to an open subset of $\Bbb R^m$ is smooth if and only if its components are smooth functions.

Answer (score 0):

A map $f \colon M^m \to N^n$ between two manifolds is smooth if and only if for any $p\in M$, there exists a chart $(U,\varphi)$ around $x\in U \subset M$ and a chart $(V,\psi)$ around $f(p) \in V\subset N$ such that the map
$$
\psi\circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}\colon \varphi(U) \subset \Bbb R^m \to \psi(V)\subset \Bbb R^n
$$
is smooth in the usual sense.
Note that by the usual compatibility of charts, the "there exists" can be substitute with "for all" in the above definition.

Let $X\colon M^m \to TM$ be a vector field.
Let $\pi \colon TM \to M$ be the canonical projection.
Let $(U,\varphi)$ be a chart on $U$, and $(\pi^{-1}(U),\Phi)$ be the associated chart of $TM$.
In these charts, $X$ has the expression
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
\Phi\circ X \circ \varphi^{-1} \colon & \varphi(U) & \longrightarrow & \Phi(\pi^{-1}(U)) = \varphi(U)\times \Bbb R^m \\
& (x^1,\ldots,x^m) & \longmapsto & \left(x^m,\ldots,x^m,X^1(x^1,\ldots,x^m),\ldots,X^m(x^1,\ldots,x^m)\right).
\end{array}
$$
Note that these $\{X^j\}$ are the same as in the usual expression $X = \sum_{j=1}^m X^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$.

Now, if $X$, is smooth, then for all chart of $M$ and $TM$, the composition should be smooth.
Applying to the pair of charts $(U,\varphi)$ and $(\pi^{-1}(U),\Phi)$ shows that the components $\{X^j\}$ of $X$ are smooth.

Reciprocally, assume that $\{X^j\}$ are smooth.
Then around any point, we have found a specific pair of charts $(U,\varphi)$ and $(\pi^{-1}(U),\Phi)$ in which $\Phi\circ X \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth.
It follows that $X$ is smooth.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer @Didier. I want to confirm if I apply the same pair to the components $\{X^j\}$ of $X$ then $$\Phi\circ X^j\circ \phi^{-1}:(x^1,\cdots,x^m)\rightarrow (x^1,\cdots,x^m, X^j(x^1,\cdots,x^m)),$$right? And can you suggest any book where I can have some example after every theoretical aspect? I was struggling to grasp the logic :( Thanks again

Comment: @N00BMaster No. $X^j$ is real valued, so it makes no sense to compose $X^j\circ \varphi^{-1}$ with $\Phi$ on the left. What is true is $X^j = \pi^{m+j} \circ \Phi \circ X \circ \varphi^{-1}$ where $\pi^k\colon \Bbb R^{2m} \to \Bbb R$ is the projection on the $k$th coordinate.